# How to make a navigation bar with the company logo the centre

Tags: html, css

[Layout of what I'mm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuRF1.png) 
I've done the top half of the nav bar and I'm trying to do the second part where the boxes (represent words), which I have circled in the image. I'm trying to directly make that section  below the logo sign centered like the image shows but I am unsure on how to do that.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: center; */
  justify-content: center;
}

header {
  background: #ffe9e3;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.business {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu {}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo"><i>LOGO</i></h1>
    <nav class=m enu>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nails</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Makeup</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Face</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class=b usiness>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Your Business</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <<div class="menu">
      <nav>
      </nav>
  </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the way you wanted it to look

CSS Part :

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333333;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background: pink;
}

.logo {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.nav > ul > li {
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

check the whole code here: https://codepen.io/the-wrong-guy/pen/GRoyKMa?editors=1100

And you have made a lot of syntax errors like not giving double quotes to the class names